# Getting error when trying to display button

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

Button not displaying correctly, instead of seeing a button I see `iclass` code.

[Button Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHe6N.jpg)

Here is the code for the buttons

```
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="{{ URL::to('/business/'.$bzname.'/admin/users/' . $user->id) }}"
                                           data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show">
                                            @lang('usersmanagement.buttons.show')
                                        </a>


                                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info"
                                           href="{{ URL::to('/business/'.$bzname.'/admin/users/' . $user->id . '/edit') }}"
                                           data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">
                                            @lang('usersmanagement.buttons.edit')
                                        </a>
```

The thing is I have this on two servers, one server works fine and shows the button correctly and the other server shows the error above which is making me think something is not installed but I can't figure out what

Comment: Are you using Laravel?

Comment: Yes using Laravel

Comment: "_Getting error when trying to display button_" What error do you get?

Comment: Just see the iclass code instead of the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{!! trans() !!}` instead of `@lang`

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="{{ URL::to('/business/'.$bzname.'/admin/users/' . $user->id) }}"
   data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show">
    {!! trans('usersmanagement.buttons.show') !!}
</a>


<a class="btn btn-sm btn-info"
   href="{{ URL::to('/business/'.$bzname.'/admin/users/' . $user->id . '/edit') }}"
   data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">
    {!! trans('usersmanagement.buttons.edit') !!}
</a>
```